# data-binding isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'd like to know what's wrong in common code.
Here it is:

```
namespace Morse_Mail{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<Message>();

        InitializeComponent();
    }


    // some code here



}

public class Message : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string subject;
    private string date;
    private string sender;
    private string id;

    public string Subject
    {
        get { return subject; }
        set { subject = value; OnPropertyChanged("Subject"); }
    }
    public string Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set { date = value; OnPropertyChanged("Date"); }
    }
    public string Sender
    {
        get { return sender; }
        set { sender = value; OnPropertyChanged("Sender"); }
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public Message(string _Subject, string _Date, string _Sender, string _ID) 
    {
        Subject = _Subject;
        Date = _Date;
        Sender = _Sender;
        ID = _ID;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}}
```

And i want to bind the listview content to the Messages ObserverableCollection.
Here comes my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="Morse_Mail.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="864.5" Width="1203.5" ResizeMode="NoResize" Title="Morse Mail" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid Height="830" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView x:Name="ListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="704" Margin="47,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
        <ListView.View >
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">
                <GridViewColumn Width="300" Header="Subject" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding subject}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Date" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Sender" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding sender}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="20" Header="ID" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

My app works, but if I use the button to add new items to Messages Collection they appear in that Collection, but nothing changes in the window.
Why isn't my data-binding working and how to

Comment: You didn't bind anything. You need to bind something to your view before data binding will work.

Answer (score 3):

You do not appear to have set a [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx). (It needs to be the object holding the property you bind to, here that is the window)

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how to do that?
I added "    DataContext = Messages;" in my code, but nothing has changed :C

Comment: @arcadia, just add `DataContext = this;` at the end of the MainWindow constructor

Comment: Right, I did it, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @arcadia: Well, the bindings are case-senesitive and should target the properties (you cannot bind fields), so you need to fix the bindings in the columns to be upper-case. Also i would recommend implementing [`INPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) on the `Messages` as well.

Comment: @H.B.: Well... I've tryed to do that and to change some other properties, but still have no idea what's wrong there...

Comment: @arcadia: You only implemented it for the Message class, i meant the `Messages` property. Casing and the DataContext are the only obvious errors i could see, you might want to read up on [debugging bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), maybe there are some other errors that the application can tell you about.